# Why my wp_enqueue_script doesnt work on some page?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

My wp_enqueue_script from my theme is working on home page and not on other page.

This is my web : https://welgo.id.

And here is not working : https://welgo.id/listing/rs-bandung-eye-center-bandung/

So on home page, all of the wp_enqueue_script that declared on Function.php load all the scripts. but on the other page, just some of the scripts are loaded.

here is my function for wp_enqueue_script:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'listingpro_scripts');

function listingpro_scripts() {


    global $listingpro_options;

    wp_enqueue_script('Mapbox', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/mapbox.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('Mapbox-leaflet', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/leaflet.markercluster.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    //wp_enqueue_script('Build', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/build.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('Chosen',THEME_DIR. '/assets/lib/chosen/chosen.jquery.js', 'jquery', '', true);   

    wp_enqueue_script('popper', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/popper/popper.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('tooltip', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/popper/tooltip.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'flickity', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/flickity.pkgd.min.js');

    wp_enqueue_script('Mmenu', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/jquerym.menu/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('magnific-popup', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/Magnific-Popup-master/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('select2', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/select2.full.min.js', 'jquery', '', true); 

    wp_enqueue_script('popup-classie', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/popup/js/classie.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('modalEffects', THEME_DIR. '/assets/lib/popup/js/modalEffects.js', 'jquery', '', true);       
    wp_enqueue_script('2checkout', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/2co.min.js', 'jquery', '', true); 

    wp_enqueue_script('Owl-Carousel',THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);  

    wp_enqueue_script('promo-ajax-script',THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/tambahan.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('news-ajax-script',THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/tambahan.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui',THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/jquery-ui.js', 'jquery', '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('Slick', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/slick/slick.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    if(class_exists('Redux')){
        $mapAPI = '';
        $mapAPI = $listingpro_options['google_map_api'];
        if(empty($mapAPI)){
            $mapAPI = 'AIzaSyDQIbsz2wFeL42Dp9KaL4o4cJKJu4r8Tvg';
        }
        wp_enqueue_script('mapsjs', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key='.$mapAPI.'&amp;libraries=places', 'jquery', '', false);   
    }
    if(!is_front_page()){
        wp_enqueue_script('pagination', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/pagination.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    }
    /* IF ie9 */
        wp_enqueue_script('html5shim', 'https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
        wp_script_add_data( 'html5shim', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

        wp_enqueue_script('nicescroll', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('chosen-jquery', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui',THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/jquery-ui.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    if(is_page_template( 'template-dashboard.php' )){
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-rating', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/bootstrap-rating.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('droppin', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/drop-pin.js', 'jquery', '', true);  
    if(is_singular('listing')){
        wp_enqueue_script('singlemap', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/singlepostmap.js', 'jquery', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('socialshare', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/social-share.js', 'jquery', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-prettyPhoto', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', 'jquery', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-rating', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/bootstrap-rating.js', 'jquery', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('Slick', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/slick/slick.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    }
    /* ==============start add by sajid ============ */
    global $listingpro_options;
    $app_view_home  =   $listingpro_options['app_view_home'];
    $app_view_home  =   url_to_postid( $app_view_home );
    if(is_page( $app_view_home ) || is_tax( 'location' ) || (is_front_page()) || is_tax( 'listing-category' ) || is_tax( 'feature' ) || (
            is_search()
            && isset( $_GET['post_type'] )
            && $_GET['post_type'] == 'listing'
    ) ){
    wp_enqueue_script('Slick', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/slick/slick.min.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    }
    /* ==============end add by sajid ============ */
    wp_enqueue_script('dyn-location-js', THEME_DIR . '/assets/js/jquery.city-autocomplete.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    //if(is_archive()){
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapsliderjs', THEME_DIR . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-slider.js', 'jquery', '', true);
    //}


    wp_register_script( 'lp-icons-colors', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/lp-iconcolor.js' , 'jquery', '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lp-icons-colors' );

    wp_register_script( 'lp-current-loc', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/lp-gps.js' , 'jquery', '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lp-current-loc' );

    wp_enqueue_script('Main', THEME_DIR. '/assets/js/main.js', 'jquery', '', true); 





    if ( is_singular('post') && comments_open() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
```

I already tried disabling plugins but still there is an error that my jquery-ui.js is not loaded.

I wonder why. Im not good at php and wordpress so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Hi add this code to your Function.php and jquery-ui.js should be loaded correctly on your website.

// Register Script
    function custom_scripts() {

```
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', '/assets/js/jquery-ui.js', false, false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: It's unclear what this code does, where to add this code, or how it solves the original question. Could you [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/324658/edit) using the [edit link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/324658/edit) above and add an explanation on what this code does please? The idea is that answers should educational and informational, code only answers may be poorly received by the community.